# Detect video or audio track in a raw MP4 data

Tags: java, video, mp4, mp4parser

is there a way to detect either a `Video` or `Audio` track present in a raw `MP4` data?

I have downloaded a raw `MP4` data (with some size) from a URL with a range request. It is not a full `MP4` data.

I am using `MP4Parser` to do this job.

What I have tried is I am trying to build a `Movie` object from the above `MP4` data. But it throws `exception` saying that `there are no tracks` in it.

Any idea would be much appreciated how to construct Movie object from a raw `MP4` data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

without the original moov box, the file is pretty much worthless. It is possible to locate the frames in the mdat and reconstruct a new moov with some forensic analysis, but its almost certainly not work the effort or cost dot so.

Comment: how can we located frames in "mdat" ? Will MP4Parser can do that?

Comment: By hand with a hex editor, or with statistical forensic analysis. No mp4parser can not do that. This is akin to recovering a deleted file off a hard drive.

Comment: When I say it’s possible, i mean it possible theoretically, not that there is a automated tool that can accomplish it.